# How to adding two method returns together

Tags: java, methods, return-value

Ok, So I have a method

```
public static int getTotalLegCountDog (ArrayList<Dog> dogList)
{

    int temp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dogList.size(); i++)
    {
        temp = dogList.get(i).getNumLegs();
        totalLegsDogs += temp;
    }
    return totalLegsDogs;
}
```

It adds up the total legs of dogs and returns them as totalLegsDogs and there is another that totals the legs for cats.

Now I'd like a method that would take both the returned totalLegsDogs and returned totalLegsCats and add them together. My try is below (It returns 0), any help would be great!

```
public int getTotalLegCount ()
{
    totalLegs = totalLegsDogs + totalLegsCats;
    return totalLegs;
}
```

Comment: both methods are ran before the total method and both methods are outputted before the total method.

Comment: Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that provides context as to how you're calling these methods, what the data looks like and how and where the variables are defined.

Comment: Where are `totalLegs`, `totalLegsDogs`, and `totalLegsCats` variables defined?

Comment: They are defined outside of the method.

Answer (score 0):

Was not calling the Method correctly. The math in the Problem was solid. The problem was the Method output call.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there's nothing wrong with the methods themselves - likely you're calling `getTotalLegCount` before actually counting the legs.

**Fix 1** (preferred): Have `getTotalLegCount` call the methods.

```
public int getTotalLegCount (ArrayList<Dog> dogList, ArrayList<Cat> catList) {
  totalLegs = getTotalLegCountDog(dogList) + getTotalLegCountCat;
  return totalLegs;
}
```

**Fix 2**: Make it *very* clear that the leg-counting methods are to be called first. This is the inferior solution, as it requires more effort on the future programmer's part (and that might be future-you!).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you've shown us enough of your code to do any troubleshooting. It looks like you must have a global static count for dog legs and cat legs? I can't figure out your use case, but any rate, you need to make sure both your counting methods are called before you do anything with the member variables or else they will not be initialized. Example:

```
DogCatCounter.getTotalLegDogCount(...);
DogCatCounter.getTotalLegCatCount(...);
new DogCatCounter().getTotalLegCount();
```

The result from that third line should be correct as long as no other instances of `DogCatCounter` have modified your static variables. In other words, if you have multiple instances of `DogCatCounter`, any calls to your counting methods are going to modify your global static members.